# Groovy eachWithIndex multiple statements

Tags: groovy

I found this example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5591274/4587961

but it has a single statement

```
def numbers = [ 5, 7, 9, 12 ]
numbers.eachWithIndex{ num, idx -> println "$idx: $num" }
```

How do I perform multiple statements

for example

```
def functionWithMultipleStateements(Object o, int index) {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    println (a + b)
    println o
    println index
}

numbers.eachWithIndex{ num, idx -> functionWithMultipleStateements "$idx: $num" }
```

It works well. However, when I try to

```
numbers.eachWithIndex{ num, idx ->  
    {
        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;
        println (a + b) + " " + "$idx: $num"
    }
}
```

compilation fails. I do not want to declare additional function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].eachWithIndex { num, idx ->  
  int a = 2
  int b = 3
  println "${a + b} ${idx}: ${num}"
}
```

emulates your example, works, and produces the following output:

```
~> groovy solution.groovy 
5 0: 1
5 1: 2
5 2: 3
5 3: 4
5 4: 5
5 5: 6
5 6: 7

~>
```

You don't need the second level of curly braces. Also in your code you have misspelled `int` as `nt`, you don't need the semicolons at the line endings, and in general [groovy string interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation) is more readable than appending to the string using `+`.